# Migrating from IBM Datastage to SSIS

Tags: ssis, data-migration, datastage

Good Afternoon,

Does anyone know how to migrate IBM Datastage jobs into SSIS?

OR has anyone done it and can offer any tips and tricks or a walkthrough.

Thank you.

Comment: I am also looking for this. Seems nobody has tried to build a converter. It can be done but it will take a lot of time. The Datastage transformer would be like 5 different job types in SSIS. Datastage has the configuration all over the place.